# から and より used one after the other

Tags: particle-から

I came across a statement in my Japanese book and wondered if someone could help me out with it.

> (　　)の中からより適当な方を選びなさい。

I reckon this translates to from the ( ) choose the most appropriate option.

But why is からより used? Shouldn’t it be one or the other as they both have the same meaning?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5556/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5539/9831

Comment: @Dave07, I am baffled that we came across this doubt the very same day... Your textbook is Tobira grammar power exercises for mastery, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that’s the one! 
That’s strange hey!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they do not. Not in this context. から means from, and より means more, which is an adverb modifying 適当な.

[Article 4 of the jisho page for より](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A) has an example sentence:

> **より**いい物が見つからないので、今ある物で我慢しよう

Comment: Understood, thank you!!